# Windows Azure deployment problem

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm having a problem with deploing my solution to Windows Azure.

I've created a basic ASP.NET web role and tried to run that against my local DevFabric and everything is running perfectly. The ASP.NET site is reachable via a browser, I can see the valid results of executed code and everything is perfect.

Later on, I tried to deploy that to Windows Azure, the exactly same solution that I run against my local fabric and it was deployed successfully. Azure "told" me that the solution is ready (the green icon).

When I try to reach my service's url, I'm getting 10060 timeouts, as if the url is not reachable at all. This is for both, the staging and production environment.

I tried to look into the diagnostic logs, but there is nothing mentioned about any problems, moreover, the traces created by my application are written to the WADLogsTable, that indicates that the application is actualy running and it executed (at least some of) my code, but it's it's not reachable via the browser.

What is wrong with that, or what I'm doing wrong?

Service definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="CloudServiceX"     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="WebRole1">
    <InputEndpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </InputEndpoints>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Azure team and they told me that they had network-related issues inside their data center.

Call the support and they should resolve the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `HTTP/HTTPS endpoint` is enabled in your web role

Comment: Also check for Database/Storage account connection and there is no default proxy set in your web.config file